# Typescript paths from tsConfig.app.json not resolving when running JEST

Tags: typescript, jestjs, angular9, ts-jest

I have this settings for paths in my tsconfig.app.json:

```
"paths": {
    "@app/core": ["./src/app/core"]
}
```

Whenever I run a test that has import statements with relative path I get the following error:

```
Cannot find module '@app/core' or its corresponding type declarations

import {NotificationService} from "@app/core"
```

How can i configure my jest.config.js file to resolve this issue?

I have tried setting as

```
moduleNameMapper: { 
    "@app/core": "<rootDir>/src/app/core" 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because it's `tsconfig`, not `tsConfig`, which will get ignored.

Comment: Its set as tsconfig